# Passign List of interface as parameter in a function

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I am sure that I have a silly bug but I am unable to pass a list of objects that implements an interface to a function that requires a list of that interface.

This is the function signature:

```
public void add(ArrayList<PairStringInterface> data){ ... }
```

And this is how I am calling this function:

```
ArrayList<Sector> list = new ArrayList<Sector>();
add(list);
```

And this is the class Sector

```
public class Sector implements PairStringInterface { ... }
```

I receive an error that there isn't any suitable function for the parameters

```
Error:(88, 31) error: no suitable method found for add(ArrayList<Sector>) 
method PairStringSpinnerAdapter.add(ArrayList<PairStringInterface>) 
is not applicable (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Sector> cannot be converted to ArrayList<PairStringInterface>)
```

If I iterate the list and add a method to receive just one item it works.

```
public void add(PairStringInterface elem) { ... }

ArrayList<Sector> list = ....
for(Sector s : list){
    add(s);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a generic type placeholder, like follow

```
public <T extends PairStringInterface> void add(ArrayList<T> list) {
    // Do your things here...
}
```

Changing the method signature as above you should be able to use any `ArrayList<Sector>` passed as an argument to that very method.

Comment: Yep, corrected, thanks @AlexSifuentes

Comment: Or `public void add(ArrayList<? extends PairStringInterface> list)`